# css temporarily broken when the page load ( .addClass )

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using a wordpress plugin who allows me to generate filters fields.
I can't modify the css directly in the plugin so I use `.addClass`.

The problem is when the page is loading, the plugin display briefly the fields without the class I added in Jquery.

How can I display directly these fields with appropriate class ?
I tried to bypass the problem with a preloader but on mobile device, loading is too long.

[You can check it here](http://www.capitainebar.com/recherche)

My code :

`$("[data-id='1']").addClass( "grid-33 suffix-66 tablet-grid-33 tablet-suffix-66 mobile-grid-50 mobile-suffix-50 bloc-arrondissement" );
$("[data-id='2']").addClass( "grid-33 tablet-grid-33 mobile-grid-100 slider-prix" );
$("[data-id='3']").addClass( "grid-33 tablet-grid-33 mobile-grid-100 slider-prix" );
$("[data-id='4']").addClass( "grid-33 tablet-grid-33 mobile-grid-100 slider-prix" );`

Comment: The only real solution is to modify the template directly before it reaches the browser. Anything you do client-side will result in the FOUC you are seeing.

Comment: I can specify some class directly in the plugin, but the first field generated mustn't have the same class as the other; and without Jquery I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You need to take advantage of the WordPress `wp_enqueue_style()` functionality and override the CSS as you need to.

It looks like the plugin is queuing it's CSS as 'sf-style-css'. So if you enqueue a style making that a dependancy, it will make sure to load your CSS right after it allowing you to override the styles. You could literally copy that style sheet and modify it right in your theme directory.

Here's a basic example for your theme's functions.php file.

```
function add_my_scripts_and_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style-overrides', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/my-style-overrides.css', 'sf-style-css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_scripts_and_styles' );
```

The full reference is available here... http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Comment: If I understand well, `wp_enqueue_style()` allow me to override the CSS of my plugin without deleting it ?
Usefull, but in my case I need to add some class, not editing class who already exist

Comment: Why do you need to add a class?

Comment: Because because all the fields shouldn't be styled in the same way.
I'm using Unsemantic ( like 960 grid framework css ) so I had to push some class on my fields to make them responsive

Comment: So what's wrong with using CSS then? fieldset[data-id="1"] { background-color: #777; }